# Erro ao atribuir objeto a outra classe

Tags: java, array

No código ele seta os valores dos empregados com o primeiro valor digitado e ignora os outros.

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
            Empregados f = new Empregados();
            System.out.println("Qual é o salario do "  + (i+1) + " empregado? ");
            f.salario = entrada.nextDouble();
            f.numero = i + 1;
            e.adiciona(f);
        }
```

qual o erro no metodo?

classe empresa:

```
public class Empresa {

    String nome;
    String localidade;
    Empregados[] empregados;
    int numFuncionarios;

    Empresa(String nome, String localidade) {
        empregados = new Empregados[3]; 
        numFuncionarios = 0;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.localidade = localidade;

    }

    void adiciona(Empregados e) {
        while(numFuncionarios < 3) {
            empregados[numFuncionarios] = e;
            numFuncionarios++;
        }

    }

    void mostraDadosEmpresa() {
        System.out.println("Nome: " + this.nome);
        System.out.println("Localidade: " + this.localidade);
        for(int count=0; count < empregados.length; count ++) {
            System.out.println("Empregado n." + (count + 1) + "salario: " + empregados[count].getSario());
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: O que é essa variavel `e`?

Comment: é da empresa: Empresa e = new Empresa();

Comment: Tem só duas variaveis, a de salario e numero

Comment: Empresa é uma lista? Adiciona a implementação dela na pergunta tambem, e da classe empregados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O loop do seu método `adiciona()` vai adicionar sempre um único funcionário nas três posições, e toda vez que você adicionar outro funcionário, o loop vai adicionar esse funcionário por cima das três posições novamente. Para resolver, remova o loop e use uma condição `if`:

```
void adiciona(Empregados e) {
    if(numFuncionarios < 3) {
        empregados[numFuncionarios] = e;
        numFuncionarios++;
    }
}
```